# <runtime> Maven dependencies transitivity

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

Think to a dependency tree like **A-->B-->C**. Assume that B is *compile* within A.

If C has a *compile* scope within B then, when compiling A, C will be included to the A's classpath.

If C has a *provided* scope within B then, when compiling A, C will NOT be included to the A's classpath unless A declares C e.g. as a *compile* dependency.

If C has a *runtime* scope within B, when **running** A in a devoted container, will C be available to the A's classpath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming A->B is "compile", it will be a runtime dependency for A. This is explained in the table (scroll down):

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

It pretty much summarizes the whole transitivity/scope problem.

Comment: Thanks. Stemming from this table we can easily deduce that a runtime transitive dependency C will be shipped in the final artifact, because it is going to be in turn a runtime dependency for the main project.